# Как правильно писать и произносить фразу

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: ***"не справился с управлением автомобил(Я)"*** или ***"не справился с управлением автомобил(ЕМ)"***?

Answer (score 1):

В данном значении существительное *"управление"* требует творительного падежа: *управление автомобилем, управлять автомобилем, **не справился с управлением автомобилем*** (источник: [Малый академический словарь](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/72968/%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%CC%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец спасибо за правки, я спросонья сначала сделал одну формулировку, потом переписал, но напутал и даже не заметил :)

Comment: По-моему, актуальны оба варианта. У автомобиля есть интерфейс управления. "Не справился с рулем автомобиля", "Не справился с управлением автомобиля". Смотря какой смысл закладывать в слово "управление".

Comment: @Theej глагол "справиться" неуместен в сочетании с тем смыслом сущ. "управление", которое вы указали. У "справиться" два значения: *1. сделать, выполнить что-л.; суметь сделать, выполнить что-л. С. с работой. С. с поручением. С. с задачей. 2. с кем-чем. Одержать верх, одолеть в борьбе, побороть кого-, что-л.* Конечно, в художественном стиле возможно сказать "он не сумел одолеть управление автомобиля", тем самым это управление показывая противодействующим, сложным, непонятным. Но не в таком юридическом обороте, как "не справился с управлением автомобилем": здесь первое значение "справиться".